Ubuntu 24.04 on my Acer Aspire lite AL15-41, Bluetooth, it's not finding devices
I ran lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep firm and here is the output.


As written there is no info here to be able to offer any help. Links to text do not get read. Include the text in the body of the question with cut and past. Also add a lot more detail.

Also edit the question to include results for lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep firm

@Jeremy31 the output has been included in the question

What is the wifi device?  Results for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net  If it is Realtek 8852 I can patch my repo at github for it

@Jeremy31 the device is
Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM

That isn't wifi

Check in terminal mokutil --sb as Secure Boot has to be disabled, then in terminal
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.8
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
Reboot
